# Scala constructor with multiple parameters

Tags: scala, constructor

Please help me understand.

My questions:
I have N parameters in class constructor (check below Email class),
1. How to create multiple Auxiliary constructors?
2. How to pass a method value into constructor parameter?

```
class Email (
  private val firstName: String,
  private val lastName: String,
  private val domain: String,
  private var emailCapacity,
  private var alterEmail,
  private var chngPassword){

   ....

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess by "auxiliary constructors" you mean overloads - in which case you can supply default values for some of the parameters e.g.

```
class Email (
  private val firstName: String,
  private val lastName: String,
  private val domain: String,
  private val emailCapacity=100,
  private val alterEmail=false,
  private val chngPassword=true)
```

you can then call it like val `em=new Email("a","b","mydomain.com",alterEmail=true)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also create auxiliary constructors as follows:

```
class Email private (firstname: String, lastName: String, domain: String, emailCapacity: String, alterEmail: String, chgpassord: String) {
  def this(firstname: String) = this(firstname, "", "", "", "", "")
}
```

This might make sense if you want to reduce the flexibility and allow only specific constructors.